# A measurable set that acts as a speedometer

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, recreational-mathematics

**Definitions and some motivation:**

Say a car is driving on a straight road. All we know is where it starts, and how much time it spends in certain stretches of the road. With just this much information, can we pinpoint the exact trajectory of the car?

Translating this loosely to math - does there exist a measurable subset $S$ of $\mathbb R$ such that any absolutely continuous $f: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ with $f(0) = 0$ is determined entirely by how much time it spends in $S$?

More precisely, denote by $\mathcal C_0$ the subset of absolutely continuous, real valued functions $f$ on $[0, \infty)$ such that $f(0) = 0$.
For any measurable subset $S$ of $\mathbb R$, and
any $f \in \mathcal C_0$, define the function $T(f): [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ by

$T(f)(x) := \mu(\{t|\ t \in [0, x), f(t) \in S \})$.

**Question:**

Does there exist a measurable subset $S$ of $\mathbb R$ such that the operator on $\mathcal C_0$ sending $f$ to $T(f)$ is injective?

*Note: Here $\mu$ denotes the usual Lebesgue measure.*

Comment: It seems to me that $T$ is not injective on constant functions. Did I miss something?

Comment: With the condition that $f(0) = 0$, there is only one constant function!

Comment: It's clear that neither $S$ nor its complement can contain any interval, as then we could have two different functions which travel to that interval at the same speed, and then stay in that interval for the rest of time, following different paths.

Comment: Yep, also $S$ (and it’s complement) have to be “fractal” in the sense that there is no absolutely continuous (non identity) homeomorphism $h$ from intervals $I$ to $J$ such that $h(S \cap I) = S \cap J$ modulo null sets.

Comment: Note that by differentiating $T(f)$ we recover the function $1_S(f(t))$ a.e., so we might as well ask whether $f \mapsto 1_S \circ f$ can be injective (up to null sets).

Comment: @Nate Eldredge That’s a good idea. Though I think it’s more so something like $1_S (f(t))$ over $|f’(t)|$.

Comment: Oh wait never mind, it’s indeed $1_S (f(t))$.

Answer (score 3):

No, $T$ cannot be injective.

---

If $S \cap (a, b)$ has zero Lebesgue measure, then $T$ will assign the same value to $f_1$ and $f_2$ if, say, $f_1(t) = f_2(t)$ for $t < 1$ and $f_1(t), f_2(t) \in (a, b)$ for $t \geqslant 1$, and $f_1'(t) \ne 0$ and $f_2'(t) \ne 0$ for $t \geqslant 1$.

Suppose that $S \cap (a, b)$ has a positive Lebesgue measure for every interval $(a, b)$, and write $$\phi(x) = \int_0^x \mathbb 1_S(y) dy$$ (that is, $\phi(x) = \mu(S \cap [0, x))$ for $x \geqslant 0$ and $\phi(x) = -\mu(S \cap [x, 0))$ for $x < 0$). Then $\phi$ is strictly increasing, and therefore the inverse function $\psi = \phi^{-1}$ is well-defined. We claim that $\psi(t) \in S$ for almost all $t \in \mathbb R$. This shows that if $f_1(t) = \psi(t)$ and $f_2(t) = \psi(-t)$, then $T(f_1) = T(f_2)$. Thus, it remains to prove our claim.

---

Observe that
$$ t = \phi(\psi(t)) = \int_0^{\psi(t)} \mathbb 1_S(y) dy = \int_0^t \mathbb 1_S(\psi(s)) d\psi(s) . $$
Therefore, $\mathbb 1_S(\psi(s)) \ne 0$ for almost all $s$ with respect to $d\psi$. Furthermore, since $0 < \phi(y) - \phi(x) \leqslant y - x$ when $x < y$, we have $\psi(t) - \psi(s) \geqslant t - s$ when $s < t$. In particular, the Lebesgue measure is absolutely continuous with respect to $d\psi$. It follows that $\mathbb 1_S(\psi(s)) \ne 0$ for almost all $s$ also with respect to the Lebesgue measure, as claimed.

Comment: Hm, is $\psi$ guaranteed to be absolutely continuous? I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: No, $\psi$ is typically not absolutely continuous.

Comment: Ah. So like I guess the original formulation of the problem (before my last edit 10 hours ago) didn’t have the absolutely continuous stipulation. If you read the initial version and came up with this, my apologies. I will accept the answer if that’s the case since this does answer the question as originally posed.

Comment: Ah, I did not notice that $C_0$ only contains *absolutely* continuous functions, sorry! Time permitting, I'll think about that and I will try to update my answer.

Comment: Ah no problem. I did consider using some other notation other than $\mathcal C_0$.. wonder why I stuck with it. Regardless, thanks for your efforts thus far!